# Can you Install Powershell Modules on MacOS?

Tags: macos, powershell

I have Powershell Core installed on my Mac (using homebrew) and it works great for coding in VS Code. However, I need to add additional modules (primarily for code-completion/hints) to assist with my coding.

Is this possible? For example, right now I need to add the "webadministration" module, but when I try `install-module webadministration` it is not found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Install-Module` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module) installs modules from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) - on all supported platforms, including macOS.

However, currently no module named `webadministration` exists there, though there are similarly named ones: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=webadministration

You can perform the equivalent search from PowerShell via the [`Find-Module` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/find-module):

```
Find-Module *webadministration*
```